# Automatic text replacement in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, autohotkey, text-editing

So, I'm looking for a software native to gnome that provides automatic text replacement. Something similar to autohotkey would be great, though I really don't care about all that extra autohotkey functionality. I'm just looking for text replacement that works seamlessly while I'm typing wherever I'm typing.

I've heard that autohotkey runs on wine, but I'd really rather install something native to unix. Is there a software like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). I'm just starting with it, but it seems that it will do the job.

[image]

Comment: That's great. Does it also support special key presses? (Such as pressing the up key)

Comment: Just tried it, and Yes!