# Text input replacement utility

Tags: linux

Is there any utility program which will replace or insert some extra text when I write some text combination in some text input?

Example, when I write "html", the program should replace "html" with "Hyper Text Markup Language".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [stream editor (sed)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) command ([man page](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/sed.html)) to replace text in a file. E.g., if you had saved what you typed in a file called myfile.txt, you could use the command below to replace all instances of 
"html" with "Hyper Text Markup Language":

```
sed -i -e 's:html:Hyper Text Markup Language:Ig' myfile.txt
```

The `-i` option instructs sed that you want to edit the file in place, i.e., store the changes in the file it is processing. The `-e` indicates that what follows will be the expression/command for sed to run. The command that sed should execute is enclosed by the single quotes. The `s` tells it to perform a substitution of the text that follows the first colon with the text that follows the second colon. You don't necessarily have to use colons as the separators; you could use another character such as a slash character, i.e., `/`. The `I` after the last colon tells it to ignore the case of letters, so it will replace "HTML" as well as "html". If you only wanted to replace "html", you would omit the `I`. The g tells it to perform a "global" replace, which ensures that if "html" occurs more than once on a line, sed will replace all occurrences of "html" with the replacement text. [Other examples of sed text replacement](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/commands/sed-replace.php).

Perhaps you could [use Autokey for the automatic text replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/121656/automatic-text-replacement-in-ubuntu). If it isn't available using the package management utility you normally use for software installations, it is available from GitHub at [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). See [AutoKey : Linux Utility for Text Substitution , Hotkeys and Desktop Automation](https://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/autokey-linux-utility-for-text-substitution-hotkeys-and-desktop-automation/) for information on installation and usage of the utility.

Comment: But I'm looking for a way to do this on Standard Input, not on content in text file.

Comment: @Mario Velickovsk, I haven't used it myself, but perhaps AutoKey may suit your requirement; I've updated my post with information on that utility.

Comment: @MarioVelickovski I've used Autohotkey with much success in Windows for text replacement like you're talking about, but I've never tried it in Linux.